# HashMap with key as generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I have an `interface dest` and some classes implementing this interface:

```
class destImpl1 implements dest { ... } 
class destImpl2 implements dest { ... }
```

I then have a `HashMap<dest,double> destHash`. What I want is to instantiate `destHash` like so:

```
destHash = new HashMap<destImpl1,double>();
```

and later like this:

```
destHash = new HashMap<destImpl2,double>();
```

but the code doesn't compile. What am I missing here?

Comment: Java Generics does not support primitive types. You need to use the boxed `Double` class.

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: @Gaber-ber my error is: Type mismatch: cannot convert from LinkedHashMap<Dest,Double> to HashMap<destImpl1,Double>

Comment: I'm more worried about what you're trying to achieve here. While you can get these lines to compile using an upper-bounded wildcard you won't actually be able to use the `destHash` to store anything if you do.

Comment: @AndyBrown can you please explain why is that (the storing problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare `destHash` as:

```
HashMap<? extends dest, Double> destHash
```

This says "A `HashMap` where `K` is an unknown type that has the upper bound `dest`".

The reason is that `Foo<Y>` is not a subtype of `Foo<X>` even when `Y` is a subtype of `X`. However `Foo<? extends X>` represents the set of all possible generic type invocations of `Foo<T>` where the type parameter is a subtype of `X`. For more details see [The Java Tutorials > Upper Bounded Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

Note that you need to use the wrapper type `Double` instead of the primitive as the second type argument.

Comment: *However, if you do this you may not be able to actually use the `HashMap` as you won't be able to `put` keys and values into it. This suggests your design may be incorrect (see [Guidelines for Wildcard Use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html))*.

Comment: I'm rewriting some "historic" code , and this will greatly reduce the amount of work I need to do , can you explain please why I wont be able to use the hashmap ?

Comment: also you are correct about the value type , I wrote it just for the example

Comment: @LordTitiKaka. You need to read the links I put in the question. The key is to understand inheritance for generic types, then to understand lower/upper bounded wildcards and the get/set (or [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/1945631)) principle. That will help you achieve what you need to do.

Comment: your guides helped figures stuff that I didn't know before ! thanks :)